# How to send LIST while i'm doing "Modified" in mvc

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, entity, crud

Firstly one i have a Edit method in controller and 3 values are coming to my "questionList" parameter from view.
I want to use this method for "Modified" operation with this list which has 3 values but i dont know how can i do.

For ex:

```
public void Edit(List<Question> questionList)
    {
        db.Entry(questionList).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

In normal i need to use "db.Entry(SomeModel)"i know but is there any way to send this as List?

Comment: Loop through the list...?

Comment: infact it came to my mind and i tried but its tiring for DB i think.

Comment: If your underlying question is how to do bulk updates with EF, the answer is: can't do. Whatever you do, it'll always be one update statement per entity. (Assuming you're in EF6, EF-core is different).

Comment: You'r right. i will do with loop. Thanks.